# Allow IP to reach specific path/location just once in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to allow IP to access specific path once or every 24 hours? This is useful for anonymous voting. So only one vote is allowed from IP. Is there any way to use `limit_req_zone` for specific path/location and of course, longer period?

Comment: `limit_req` probably isn't what you wanted, because it's an [LRU store](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone) rather than a permanent storage. if you're limited to use only nginx, and open to using Lua, you may try [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/)'s [lua-resty-mysql](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You should implement this in your application.